# GoogleMaps Autocomplete get selected value from list

Tags: jquery, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

I am entering an address and using **Geocomplete** to show the user \a list of possible addresses. Once the user is finished typing the address, I would like to get the longitude and latitude coordinates for the address entered. I am having some issues with getting the coordinates for the selected address from the list.

I have tried jquery `blur`, `after` and `change` but it fires as soon as the list pops up. I am looking for a way to set selected address from the list in the `loopUpAdd`, once an address is selected or auto complete is completed I want to be able to get the longitude and latitude coordinates for the address. The alert in `$('#loopUpAdd').blur(function(evt){....` is showing the value of what the user typed so far and not what was selected.
Here is my fiddle [GeoCode](http://jsbin.com/itegul/11/edit)

**HTML**

```
<label>Address</label>
<input type="text" id="loopUpAdd" />
<label>Long</label>
<input type="text" id="long" />
<label>Lat</label>
<input type="text" id="lat" />
```

**JQuery**

```
function getLocation() {

    var input = document.getElementById('loopUpAdd');

    var options = {
        types: ['(cities)'],
            componentRestrictions: {country: 'tt'}
        };

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options); 
        $('#lat').val(0);
        $('#long').val(0);
    }

function codeAddress(address) {
    //var address = document.getElementById("loopUpAdd").value;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {           
            var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();

            $('#lat').val(lat);
            $('#long').val(lng);
            alert(lng +'-'+lat);
        } else {
            $('#lat').val(0);
            $('#long').val(0);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#loopUpAdd').blur(function(evt){ 
        alert($(this).val());
        codeAddress($(this).val());          
    });

    $('#loopUpAdd').mouseenter(function(evt){  
        $('#lat').val(0);
        $('#long').val(0);     
    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', getLocation);
});
```

Comment: Please also paste the code here for future reference and completeness.

Comment: I do apologize now read the rule on jsfiddles in SO

Comment: You have no `#crimeLocation` in your sample markup, so it'll never enter the branch to alert or invoke `codeAddress`. You might have more luck making a working example on http://jsbin.com

Comment: sorry i will update the code i changed it for the post

Comment: Code Updated and a link Demo provided